# How do I get an aggregated list of models' fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, model, relation

I'm using RoR 5.  I have this model

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
    ...
  has_and_belongs_to_many :contributors, :optional => false
```

Then let's say I have an array of article models.  How do I get the complete list of contributors?  I tried this ...

```
articles.each do |article|
  @contributors << article.contributors
end
@contributors
```

But when I try and access attributes of the contributors in a view, like "id", I get these errors

```
undefined method `id' for #<Contributor::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x00007f828a834028>
```

WHat's the correct way to aggregate the list of contributors?

Comment: You have literally an `array` of `Article`s? Or, you have some other sort of ActiveRecord `enumerable`, like a `relation`? Have you called `has_and_belongs_to_many :articles` in your `Contributor` model?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
@contributors = Contributor.joins(:articles).where(articles: {id: articles})
```

You can check out [Specifying Conditions on the Joined Tables](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-the-joined-tables) in the [docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) for more information.

This assumes, naturally, that

```
class Contributor < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :articles
end
```

You're getting this error:

```
undefined method `id' for #<Contributor::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x00007f828a834028>
```

...because you're creating an `array` of `ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy`s here:

```
articles.each do |article|
  @contributors << article.contributors
end
@contributors
```

...since:

```
article.contributors
```

...returns an `ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy`. And, naturally, an `ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy`, as the error says, doesn't have the method `id`

Comment: Did this help? What did you end up doing?